# Dynamically read in Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem. I spent hours designing a form which works just great with all your feedback. Today, everything went wrong. The reason for this is simple. A few new columns got added and, obviously, the data my form is reading in is now wrong.

Thus I was thinking of trying the following...

Rather than using the column number as below

```
TK = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "S").Value 'everything in the form refers to the active row
```

I could possibly use the column headings in Row 1.

Is that possible ? This way the spreadsheet can have columns added up to as many as a user would like and the form would dynamically scan for the right heading and get the column number that way.

My thought is, on opening the form, read in all the headings, pick out the ones I need and assign them to a variable. Then I use my normal code and substitute the variable into the column section.

It sounds easy, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: `Cells` function requires numbers, like Cells(5,2). Replace "S" by its number. And write your question to be more generic. Most people have little or no idea about what is a Coulomb and they don't care. It just makes your question look weird, having nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @iDevlop, you are wrong, both `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "S")` and `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 19)` are correct!

Comment: Think of using named ranges: 1. select range and give it a name, like S1 could have name `dataAColumnHeading` (could be done with VBA but try to do it manually), 2. in your vba code you could call that range like this: `Range("dataAColumnHeading")`... If someone inserts additional columns, rows or delete any of them you would always keep references to cell named `dataAColumnHeading`...

Comment: @iDevlop. I am surprised at the comment. If people do not know what a row or a coulomb is, then they should not have a clue what Excel is and hence should not even attempt answering the question.

Comment: @Haissan: Ok, now I understand: I think you mean a column !

Comment: @KazJaw: +1 I did not know that - and I thought I knew most of Excel...so I was definitely wrong there. Good that I learned something today.

Comment: @iDevlop, sry bout the spelling on my side. Just saw my mistake. Hope you all having a smile about it. Yes was supposed to be a column. Joke is on me.

Comment: @KazJaw Agreed. A Named range is also a good suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the versatile `Find` to give you a quick method of detecting where your header is - or if it is missing

[Find details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

In the code below I have specified that the search must return

- an exact match (`xlWhole`)
- a case sensitive match (`False`)

The match can be a partial match (`xlPart`) if you were looking to match say *Game* out of *Game X*

**code**

```
Const strFind = "Game"

Sub GetEm()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Your column is " & rng1.Column
Else
MsgBox strFind & " not found", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good one! `.Find` is so under utilized :(

Answer (score 3):

Why use a loop? There's no need to.

```
Dim col as variant 
Col = application.match("my header", rows(1), 0)
If iserror(col) then
    'not found
Else
    TK = cells(activecell.row, col)
End if
```

Comment: why assume a successful match?

Comment: @brettdj As i don't know the context i suggest the op puts this in as required. Depending on the implementation the op may be happy with this. But i admit it is foolish to assume such a thing.

Comment: @brettdj i've amended based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I usually use a function which runs through the headers (in the first row of a sheet) and returns the number of the column which contains the value I have searched for.

```
Public Function FindColumn(HeaderName As String, Sht As String) As Long

Dim ColFound As Boolean
Dim StartingPoint As Range

ColFound = False

Set StartingPoint = Sheets(Sht).Range("A1")
Do While StartingPoint.Value <> ""
    If UCase(Trim(StartingPoint.Value)) = UCase(Trim(HeaderName)) Then
        FindColumn = StartingPoint.Column
        ColFound = True
        Exit Do
    Else
        Set StartingPoint = StartingPoint.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
Loop
If Not ColFound Then FindColumn = 0

End Function
```

*Example*: 
If the first row of your sheet named "Timeline" contains headers like e.g. "Date" (A1), "Time" (B1), "Value" (C1) then calling `FindColumn("Time", "Timeline")` returns 2, since "Time" is the second column in sheet "Timeline"

Hope this may help you a little.

Comment: @glh: Sounds great, but I guess it should be `Col = application.**WorksheetFunction**.match("my header", rows(1), 0)`

Comment: Also very nice, definitely keeping this snippet, but again, I need all headers indexed and the numbers stored to be substituted into the current code. I amended the problem above to be a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your thought is a good one. Reading in column headers to calculate addresses is one way to avoid hard coding - e.g.

```
Sub Test()
Dim R As Range

    Set R = ActiveSheet.[A1]
    Debug.Print ColNo(R, "Col1Hdr")
End Sub

Function ColNo(HdrRange As Range, ColName As String) As Integer
    ' 1st column with empty header is returned if string not found
    ColNo = 1
    Do While HdrRange(1, ColNo) <> ""
        If HdrRange(1, ColNo) = ColName Then Exit Do
        ColNo = ColNo + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Another way I frequently use - and I must admit I prefer it over the above, is to define `Enum`'s for all my tables in a seperate "definition" module, e.g.

```
Public Enum T_VPN   ' sheet VPN
    NofHRows = 3    ' number of header rows
    NofCols = 35    ' number of columns
    MaxData = 203   ' last row validated
    GroupNo = 1
    CtyCode = 2
    Country = 3
    MRegion = 4
    PRegion = 5
    City = 6
    SiteType = 7
    ' ....
End Enum
```

and use it like

```
Sub Test1()
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet(T_VPN.NofHRows, T_VPN.Country)
End Sub
```

As you can see, the usage is simpler. Allthough this is again "some kind" of hardcoding, having all definition in one place reduces maintenance significantly.

Comment: i like this approach, but as you say there is hard-coding, which if forgotten just recreates the problem.